# Thread execution order in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have a list of thread I want to ensure the execution order between them this is the code

```
for (int k = 0; k < RadioList.Count; k++)
{                                     
    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Count(); i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
        {                                  
            Thread_Encde_function(TempRadio.PublishPoint, filePaths[i], encodingtype);
        });
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

I want to know if `thread.join()` can do the job.

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure the execution order"? Can you explain more?

Comment: If you need to guarantee execution order, why not just execute the function synchronously? If you're worried about blocking the UI thread, you could execute them all on the same background thread.

Comment: No, `Thread.Join()` won't do the job. Take a look at [MSDN: Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 8):

If your tasks can execute asynchronously (out of order), then threads are appropriate. However, if you have a number of tasks you want to execute in order (strictly one after the other), then why use threads? You should just execute them in your for loop, as they can't be parallelized. Using `Thread.Join` to wait for the thread right after you start it will do the trick, but that way you will have to wait until a task is finished before starting the next one, effectively executing them in order.

However, if you have some parts of the tasks that can be executed simultaneously, and other parts that have to be sequential, you can take a look at the [C# Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx), it makes doing things like that easy.

Comment: ok as referred can I loop them in one thread then put a join to wait until it finish, because i will repeate this function many times as like as i put new values in the attribute filepaths , and have to wait until the first group of files to be encoded

Comment: @7addan Please read about the basic concept of asynchronous execution, threads, tasks, etc. There are plenty of resources online. If you have tasks that come from somewhere and you need something to process them as they arrive, please look up the producer-consumer pattern. In C#, it cean easily be implemented by using BlockingCollection and one separate thread.